# Magento 2.1.7 how to not display out of stock products in reorder admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, reorder

[image]How to not display out of stock products when we place reorder admin panel(Back-end)
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the below file to your custom module:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php

and change the function **initFromOrderItem** like below:

```
public function initFromOrderItem(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem, $qty = null)
{
    if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $product = $this->_objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class
    )->setStoreId(
        $this->getSession()->getStoreId()
    )->load(
        $orderItem->getProductId()
    );


    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($orderItem->getProductId());
    if($stockItem->getData('is_in_stock') != 1){
        return $this;
    }

    if ($product->getId()) {
        $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
        $buyRequest = $orderItem->getBuyRequest();
        if (is_numeric($qty)) {
            $buyRequest->setQty($qty);
        }
        $item = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
        if (is_string($item)) {
            return $item;
        }

        if ($additionalOptions = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $item->addOption(
                new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                    [
                        'product' => $item->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
                    ]
                )
            );
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'sales_convert_order_item_to_quote_item',
            ['order_item' => $orderItem, 'quote_item' => $item]
        );
        return $item;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

No need to change anything.

Comment: Its not working for me Sukumar Gorai...

Comment: When i search for product that is out of stock should not display.. Sukumar Gorai...

Comment: This will not add out of products from that order. According to requirement this is correctly working. Try to change it in vendor folder and then test.

Comment: I have followed as above you said but when i place reorder from admin panel product of out stock its successfully order placed  Sukumar Gorai..

Comment: According to the answer it removes the product which is out of stock and added the products which are in stock. Clear the cache and test again. This will work from admin only.

Comment: Its not working for me Sukumar Gorai...

Comment: Where did you change and what you have changed. Update the file names and path.

Comment: In this /vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php path
file Create.php complete function initFromOrderItem i have replaced..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83786/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-trilok-kumar).